# Apache mod_rewrite : redirect according to browser langage

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know this question has already been asked, and I've tried to understand the solutions proposed  but I'm stucked due to my lack of knowledge of Apache (total newby).

I want to redirect my users to a localized html file according to their browser langage, and I want this file to be served by a SEO friendly URL (eg. .../fr, .../en)

My site only contains two html files (index.html and mentions.html)

What I've understood and done so far :

```
# Catch "french" requests
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^fr [NC]

# Redirect to another URL
RewriteRule ^$ /my-domain.fr/fr [L,R=301] 


# And same thing for english people
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /my-domain.fr/en [L,R=301]
```

This is OK. Now I don't know how to make those new URL (`/my-domain.fr/fr` and `/my-domain.fr/en`) serve my `index-fr.html` and `index-en.html` files.

By experiencing I found out that this one kind of work :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index-fr.html [PT]
```

But this causes of course all of my requests to be redirected to my index-fr.html file (images, js, css, ...). So it might just be the condition of the rule that needs to be more precise ?

Also, I'd like to know if the redirection flags I've mentionned are corrects.

Thank you to anyone who can help me to understand.